# Palíndromo en Javascript, ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Tags: javascript

He comenzado a aprender el lenguaje javascript hace unas horas, y me he quedado atascado en un ejercicio.

El ejercicio dice lo siguiente:

> Definir una función que determine si la cadena de texto que se le pasa como parámetro es un palíndromo, es decir, si se lee de la misma forma desde la izquierda y desde la derecha.
>
> Ejemplos:
>
> - *"la ruta nos aporto otro paso natural"*
> - *"anita lava la tina"*

Pero estoy atascado tratando de resolverlo, y no se que puede estar mal.

Este es el código que tengo:

```
var frase = prompt("Ingrese la frase o palabra: ");

function palindromo(fra) {
    // Convierto la cadena a minúscula
    var minuscula = fra.toLowerCase();
    alert(minuscula);
    // Convierto la cadena en un array
    var convertirArray = minuscula.split("");
    alert(convertirArray);
    // Elimino los espacios del array
    var sinEspacios = "";
    for (i in convertirArray) {
        if (convertirArray[i] != " ") {
            sinEspacios += convertirArray[i];
        }
    }
    alert(sinEspacios);
    // Vuelvo a convertir en array
    var nuevoArray = sinEspacios.split("");
    var alReves = nuevoArray.reverse();
    alert(alReves);
    // Verifico sin son iguales
    flag = true;
    for (i in nuevoArray) {
        if (nuevoArray[i] != alReves[i]) {
            flag = false;
            break;
        };
    };
    if (flag) {
        return ("La cadena es un palíndromo.");
    } else {
        return ("La cadena NO es un palíndromo.");
    }
};

alert(palindromo(frase));
```

A partir de donde he colocado el comentario:

> // Verifico sin son iguales

Es donde "creo" que debe estar el problema, sin embargo no logro dar con la solución, alguien puede ayudarme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas.

la asignación y reversa del arreglo, cuándo haces:

```
var nuevoArray = sinEspacios.split("");
var alReves = nuevoArray.reverse();
```

Al final quedas con dos variables conteniendo el mismo arreglo (en reversa), y luego las comparas, pero siempre van a ser iguales.

Cambialo por:

```
var nuevoArray = sinEspacios.split("");
var alReves = sinEspacios.split("").reverse();
```

Y el segundo problema está en

```
for (i in nuevoArray) {
```

Ya que i será un caracter y te irá devolviendo los caracteres de nuevoArray, y eso no se corresponde con lo que luego intentas hacer abajo.

Cambialo por:

```
for (i = 0; i < nuevoArray.length; i++) {
```

no tengo forma de probarlo ahora, pero ya con eso creo que funcionará bien.

Comment: He intentado la solución que me proporcionas, pero aún así sigue sin funcionar, ya que al colocarle cualquier palabra, el resultado que obtengo siempre es: La cadena es un palíndromo. Por cierto gracias por tomar un poco de tiempo en atender a mi consulta.

Comment: ¿Las alertas son las esperadas?

Comment: Si claro amigo, las he colocado como forma de guiarme para ver en donde más o menos se encuentra el problema.

Comment: Listo, ya vi donde estaba, lee mi respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda jachguate ahora funciona a la perfección. Te agradezco a ti, y a todas las personas que se han tomado la molestia en aportar sus conocimientos y brindar ayuda para solventar esta consulta. Feliz día para todos :)

Comment: Un gusto servirte Pedro.

Answer (score 3):

te tengo una solución mucho más sencilla

```
function esPalindromo(str) 
{
    return str == str.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

Comment: Por lo pronto tendré que seguir estudiando, ya que he comenzado cone ste lenguaje hoy, y no se para que sirve la función srt, pero investigaré. Por cierto gracias por tomar un poco de tiempo en atender a mi consulta.

Comment: @PedroFumero `str` no es una función es un parámetro que recibe la función

Comment: Tienes razón, muchas gracias por la aclaración amigo!

Comment: +1 por no concentrarse en el problema sino en la solución. Un detalle @dxcorzo, fijate que en los ejemplos que dio el autor quiere ignorar los espacios. Y por otro lado, por más que sea muy sencillo, quizás conviene explicar que estás comparando 2 strings y agregar una línea con el ejemplo usándolo - `if (esPalindromo(frase)) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, exactamente, mira, te dejo el código modificado:

```
    // Verifico sin son iguales
    flag = true;
    var a = alReves.length()-1;

    for (var i=0;i<nuevoArray.length();i++) {
        if (nuevoArray[i] != alReves[a]) {
            flag = false;
            break;
        };
        a--;
    };
    if (flag) {
        return("La cadena es un palíndromo.");
    }
    else {
        return("La cadena NO es un palíndromo.");
    }
    };


    alert(palindromo(frase));
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda amigo, he probado el código y no me ha funcionado, sin embargo me causa curiosidad algo, que funcionalidad tiene el "-1" (Del código que me has proporcionado, específicamene en la tercera línea)?. No se en donde puede estar el error, ya que el códig que me envías lo veo correcto.

Comment: Cuando haces el .length() te cuenta todos los caracteres de la cadena, pero debemos tener en cuenta que la cadena empieza en 0, entonces siempre será -1, ya que el punto length en la posicion 0 [0] ya puntua como 1 caracter

Comment: Perfecto, ahora si lo comprendo. Gracias por la explicación y la ayuda amigo :)