# Revisar palindromo JavaScript

Tags: javascript

y necesito ayuda con algo que parece ser sencillo
Es una practica que requiere revisar si la palabra es un palíndromo
Técnicamente lo hice pero hay algo que el code no puede verificar, strings como este:"aaabaaaa".
Parece que omite que hay una letra demás solo porque es la misma.
Aquí mi código

```
function checkPalindrome(inputString) {
const [...palindromo] = inputString;


let validateUno = []
let validateII = []


for (let i of palindromo) {
    validateUno = i
    console.log(1 + " " + validateUno);  
}

let validateDonw = palindromo.reverse();

for (let o of validateDonw) {
    validateII = o
   //console.log(2 + " " + validateII); 
}

for(let i = palindromo.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(palindromo[i])
}


if(validateUno === validateII) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: en los `for ... of` solo asignas una letra a cada `validate `

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Palíndromo en Javascript, ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22464/pal%c3%adndromo-en-javascript-qu%c3%a9-estoy-haciendo-mal)

Answer (score 0):

**Anthony Maldonado**, probé tu código y es cierto que se omite una *'a'* en la comprobación. Para no modififcar tu código realicé una variación propia, que realiza la comprobación del Palindromo de forma eficas y en breves líneas de código.. Saludos.

```
    //SE DECLARA LA VARIABLE QUE CONTIENE LA PALABRA A COMPROBAR SI ES PALINDROMO
    var inputString = 'aaabaaaa';

//SE REALIZA LA LLAMADA A LA FUNCION 'checkPalindrome(PARAMETRO)'
//SE HACE USO DEL 'console.log()' --> PARA IMPRIMIR LA RESPUESTA RETORNADA DE LA FUNCION 'checkPalindrome(PARAMETRO)'

console.log(checkPalindrome(inputString));

//SE DECLARA LA FUNCION 'checkPalindrome(PARAMETRO)'
function checkPalindrome(str) {

    //SE INICIALIZA EL ARREGLO 'MiInputStringInverso'
    var MiInputStringInverso = [];

    //  SE COMPARA SI ES IDENTICO EL VALOR DE 'str' y 'MiInputStringInverso'
    //  OJO 'MiInputStringInverso' MEDIANTE map.call CREA UN ARRAY NUEVO CON CADA ELEMENTO DE 'str'
    //  reverse() => INVIERTE TODO EL NUEVO ARREGLO
    //  join('') => CONCATENA TODOS LOS ELEMNTOS DEL NUEVO ARREGLO
    //  LUEGO DEPENDIENDO SI LA RESPUESTA A LA COMPRACION (TRUE ? FALSE) RETORNA LA RESPUESTA PERTINENTE MEDIANTE EL OPERADOR TERNARIO

    return (str === MiInputStringInverso.map.call(str, (x) => {
        return x;
    }).reverse().join('')) ? 'Is Palindrome' : 'Not Palindrome';
}
```

Comment: Saludos @cnunezjacas, por favor edita tu respuesta agregando una explicación del cómo el código que sugieres resuelve el problema de OP, recuerda que para muchos el código puede ser muy obvio pero para los usuarios que van aprendiendo tu código será inentendible. ;)

Comment: Hola cnunezjacas, bienvenido y gracias por tu colaboración, las respuesta que son solo código, son consideradas de baja calidad, tratamos de explicar como funciona nuestra propuesta, te sugiero que edites la tuya, para evitar votos negativos y/o el cierre de la misma, ver [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.